# What are the advantages of 'setup' hook in Vue3?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3

Personally, I think the syntax of vue2 where method, props, and data are distinguished is better, but I'm curious as to why setup was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty well explained into the official guide of the migration to Vue3: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#why-composition-api

What you do call "Vue2 syntax" is actually **Options API**.
While the **Composition API** ("Vue3 syntax") is mainly for:

- not being locked to have your functions locked to specific parts of your app
- reusability of functions, mainly [Composables](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-composition-api-composables/)
- having a more "vanilla" JS syntax, rather than being more specific to Vue
- being able to use the latest advanced methods coming with Vue3

One thing to remember is that you can totally use Options API while using Vue3, it's retro-compatible and totally fine. You can even mix both in the same file too!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to bundle reactive data and functions together instead of spreading them out into data, methods, etc.

Here is a good explanation:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#why-composition-api